# Compare the relation of two file paths

Tags: java, filepath

Consider two given file paths as strings:

`/path/to/dir` and `/path/to/dir/file`

In Java, how can one test, if the later file path would represent a real file on disk, which is below or equal the directory represented by the first string. Here are some more examples to clarify this point, including some sample return values of a checking function that is questioned here:

```
/path/to/dir /path/to/dir            (true)     
/path/to/dir /path/to/dir/file       (true)
/path/to/dir /path                   (false)
/path/to/dir /path/to/dir/../../file (false)
/path/to/dir file                    (false)
/path/to/dir /path/to/dir/dir2/../   (true)
```

Would one get rid of the dots by the `File` method `.getCanonicalPath` and then check on a string level? Maybe there is a better way. I could not find out, what `File`'s `.compareTo` does exactly.

Comment: `get rid of the dots by the File method .getCanonicalPath and then check on a string level` ... It sounds like you have an idea how to answer your own question. I suggest implementing it to see if works. You can always ask about your code if you have problems.

Answer (score 3):

Please use native path operations. String operations may introduce errors due to incorrect handling of path separators, etc.

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("/home").normalize();
Path path2 = Paths.get("/home/user/filename").normalize();

path2.startsWith(path1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the canonical path, you can do this:

```
String path1 = "/path/to/dir"
String path2 = "/path/to/dir/file"

path2.beginsWith(path1);
```

This result of this will be your answer

Answer (score 0):

The `Path` class supports `equals`, enabling you to test two paths for equality.

The `startsWith` and `endsWith` methods enable you to test whether a path begins or ends with a particular string.

These methods are easy to use. For example:

```
Path path = ...;
Path otherPath = ...;
Path beginning = Paths.get("/home");
Path ending = Paths.get("foo");

if (path.equals(otherPath)) {
    // equality logic here
} else if (path.startsWith(beginning)) {
    // path begins with "/home"
} else if (path.endsWith(ending)) {
    // path ends with "foo"
}
```